# IE innerHTML start with custom tags

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

In IE when i set div's innerHTML as:

```
<abc>1<abc>
```

the innerHTML will be convert to:

```
 1</ABC>
```

because 'abc' is a custom tag. But if i set:

```
1<abc>2</abc>
```

the innerHTML will keep the 'abc' tag, so the innerHTML is:

```
1<ABC>2</ABC>
```

Ask for the description of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

... I see. You're wondering why it removes the opening  tag when you set an element's innerHTML to 1 and it keeps it when you prepend the innerHTML with a number...

lesser IE that does not support html5 tags will behave oddly. In this case it is likely interpreting the second case as a string where as the first case it is seeing it as an invalid tag and just plain erroring.

try this if you use jQuery -
instead of doing something like

```
$('#some_element').html('<abc>1</abc>'); // equal to document.getElementById('some_element').innerHTML = '<abc>1</abc>';
```

try

```
(function(){if(!/*@cc_on!@*/0)return;var e = "abc,other_custom_tags".split(',');for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){document.createElement(e[i])}})(); // add the custom tag

var elem = $('<abc>');
elem.html('1');
$('#some_element').html(elem);
```

and declare abc as a valid tag in your css:

```
abc{
    display:block;
}
```

of course, this assumes you know that abc will be a tag used on your site. if the potential tag is unknown then this may not be of much use.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the innerHTML property is not standardised (though some attempt has been made in HTML5). It is implemented differently in different browsers.